# Call controller function from directive with arguments

Tags: angularjs

I have following code:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', []);

})();


(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('MainController', MainController);

    function MainController() {
        var vm = this;

        vm.onResize = function(viewport) {
            console.log('onResize', viewport);
        };
    }

})();


(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('resize', resize);

  function resize($window) {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        callback: '&resize'
      },
      link: link
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope) {

      angular.element($window).on('resize', function() {

        scope.callback({
          width: 100,
          height: 200
        });

      });

    }
  }

})();
```

**Plnkr demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/s7x28XI08QUytTVORtaK

As you can see I am trying to create a simple resize directive with callback function which i will call after window has been resized. My problem is that I want to pass some argument to the callback function, but it simply doesn't work currently. Instead of object that I have passed to the callback `viewport` argument inside `onResize` function is `undefined`. I'm a beginner when it comes to Angular so explanation what am i doing wrong here will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That is explained here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-, under the bullet point starting with *& or &attr*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass reference of function to directive

```
<div resize="vm.onResize"></div>
```

JS

```
var directive = {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
    callback: '=resize'
  },
  link: link
};
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/tBDI2RkxvfA7XmrNkdG7?p=preview)**</kbd>